# How to make stored procedure?

Tags: php

I made a function:

```
function getAll($table)  {
    $q = "Select * from $table"; 

    $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error()); 
    return $result;
}
```

My question is: how can I make stored procedure for this function in PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by "store procedure" ?

Comment: you cannot create stored procedure in php.that can be created in SQL (DB).what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use database extensions for that if you mean to create, drop or call a stored procedure in php.
[http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php][1]